# Running multiple OpenVPN servers in different locations for the same network

Tags: openvpn

I have no idea if this is going to make sense or is even possible, but here goes:

I have a VPN server running on a physical computer attached to my work network. We use this to work remotely as well as to be able to work with remote data collection computers that can be in any part of the country at any given time. This works well but unfortunately (at the moment) we are unable to ensure uninterrupted internet/power supply to the office (...).

One solution was to move the VPN to a cloud VM. We did this and it works well. What I'm trying to figure out now is: **can I can still keep the office VPN running in a way that a client connecting to either server should be able to reach any other client that is connected to one of the servers?**

The ultimate goal here would be to have several VPN VMs geographically located to allow for lower latency when the client you're trying to reach is physically closer to you (i.e. traffic between my work desktop and my laptop goes through the office VPN, traffic between a field engineer's laptop and a data collection computer in the east coast goes through a VM running in an east coast datacenter).

Comment: Depending on the application, simply using ssh -L and -R tunnels might solve your problems without all the hassle of openvpn.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Should I open these tunnels between individual OpenVPN servers?

Comment: You might not need openvpn if the needed communications can be described by concrete tcp ports that need to be accessed - ssh can handle that on its own.

Comment: This doesn't really work for us as we need a general purpose solution for communication, one that can handle any traffic and can scale with the number of clients. OpenVPN works really well for us especially in cases where we need to route all traffic through the server.